# GC CMS Final Remark - taking too long

Tags: java, garbage-collection

we have ..a GC..issue, where are VMs will run a very long GC (1+ seconds..we have SLA requirements of <200ms).

(This is on Java 8, we have seen this from version 11 trough to the latest).

our GC settings atm:

```
-XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics
-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UseThreadPriorities
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42
-Xms3000M
-Xmx3000M
-Xmn1500M
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Xss256k
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-XX:CompileCommandFile=./../conf/hotspot_compiler
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+UseCondCardMark
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
-Xloggc:/opt/openmarket/sqs/logs/gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
```

We have tried G1, but it was worse, so we are 'sticking' with CMS atm.

anyways, here is snippet from our GC log.

it should be noted over a ~24 hour run, it executes about 4 of these, of which 2 of them..were 'long'..(we have in fact seen much longer in prod in past, 12+ seconds!!)

One thing I do not grok..is why are we seeing -> scrub string table, 0.6001941 secs
taking so long, we do not 'intern' a lot of our strings, enabling -XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics showed no interesting' activity there, from we can tell we had less then a total of 1000 interned strings, so that should not be factor.

High level summary of the gc log can be seen here:

http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTgvMDcvMjYvLS1ub2RlLTAwMS4zLS0xNS0yMi0zNA==

```
2018-07-25T18:15:52.608+0000: 30.543: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0046391 seconds
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-25T18:15:53.553+0000: 31.488: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.326/20.683 secs] [Times: user=25.25 sys=3.89, real=20.68 secs] 
2018-07-25T18:15:53.557+0000: 31.492: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 588025 K (1382400 K)]31.492: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0559721 secs]31.548: [weak refs processing, 0.0035595 secs]31.552: [class unloading, 0.0409634 secs]31.593: [scrub symbol table, 0.0051572 secs]31.598: [scrub string table, 0.0016212 secs][1 CMS-remark: 12246K(1536000K)] 600272K(2918400K), 0.1150145 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs] 
2018-07-25T18:15:53.673+0000: 31.608: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1195510 seconds
2018-07-25T18:15:53.673+0000: 31.608: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
--
2018-07-25T18:18:45.477+0000: 203.412: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0044451 seconds
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-25T18:18:51.809+0000: 209.743: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.023/67.120 secs] [Times: user=18.52 sys=6.47, real=67.11 secs] 
2018-07-25T18:18:51.812+0000: 209.747: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 595711 K (1382400 K)]209.747: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1225090 secs]209.870: [weak refs processing, 0.0048343 secs]209.875: [class unloading, 0.0408876 secs]209.916: [scrub symbol table, 0.0047264 secs]209.920: [scrub string table, 0.0042791 secs][1 CMS-remark: 54877K(1536000K)] 650589K(2918400K), 0.1843075 secs] [Times: user=0.54 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs] 
2018-07-25T18:18:51.997+0000: 209.932: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1885355 seconds
2018-07-25T18:18:52.002+0000: 209.937: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0041075 seconds
--
2018-07-26T00:06:31.084+0000: 21069.019: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0033592 seconds
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-26T00:06:56.329+0000: 21094.264: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.400/86.919 secs] [Times: user=15.48 sys=7.48, real=86.91 secs] 
2018-07-26T00:06:56.339+0000: 21094.274: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 604677 K (1382400 K)]21094.274: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1252722 secs]21094.399: [weak refs processing, 0.0084571 secs]21094.408: [class unloading, 0.1359008 secs]21094.544: [scrub symbol table, 0.0037596 secs]21094.548: [scrub string table, 0.5171769 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1274484K(1536000K)] 1879161K(2918400K), 0.7978841 secs] [Times: user=1.13 sys=0.00, real=0.80 secs] 
2018-07-26T00:06:57.138+0000: 21095.072: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.8018055 seconds
2018-07-26T00:06:57.138+0000: 21095.073: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
--
2018-07-26T09:05:41.291+0000: 53419.226: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0053130 seconds
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-26T09:06:08.087+0000: 53446.021: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 2.304/99.556 secs] [Times: user=15.49 sys=8.46, real=99.54 secs] 
2018-07-26T09:06:08.090+0000: 53446.025: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 605003 K (1382400 K)]53446.025: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1410524 secs]53446.166: [weak refs processing, 0.0134749 secs]53446.180: [class unloading, 1.0563894 secs]53447.236: [scrub symbol table, 0.0137832 secs]53447.250: [scrub string table, 0.6001941 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1431566K(1536000K)] 2036569K(2918400K), 1.8335188 secs] [Times: user=1.28 sys=0.00, real=1.83 secs] 
2018-07-26T09:06:09.924+0000: 53447.859: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.8372996 seconds
```

updated:
Here the result of different run, with less flags (but essentially the same or worse)  (ON A side node..we have been testing with parallelOld as well, which looks promising)

FLAGS:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Xms3000M
-Xmx3000M
-Xmn1500M
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Xss256k
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+UseCondCardMark
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
-Xloggc:/opt/openmarket/sqs/logs/gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
```

GC log snippets:

018-07-29T09:22:01.752+0000: 38922.964: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-29T09:22:06.888+0000: 38928.100: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.118/5.136 secs] [Times: user=5.09 sys=0.10, real=5.14 secs] 
2018-07-29T09:22:06.890+0000: 38928.102: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 184100 K (1382400 K)]2018-07-29T09:22:06.890+0000: 38928.102: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0609614 secs]2018-07-29T09:22:06.951+0000: 38928.163: [weak refs processing, 0.0026624 secs]2018-07-29T09:22:06.954+0000: 38928.166: [class unloading, 0.0369107 secs]2018-07-29T09:22:06.991+0000: 38928.203: [scrub symbol table, 0.0024052 secs]2018-07-29T09:22:06.993+0000: 38928.205: [scrub string table, 1.0810044 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1414399K(1536000K)] 1598500K(2918400K), 1.1918919 secs] [Times: user=1.17 sys=0.00, real=1.19 secs] 
2018-07-29T09:22:08.082+0000: 38929.294: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.1943563 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001797 seconds

2018-07-29T18:52:55.303+0000: 73176.515: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-29T18:53:00.352+0000: 73181.564: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.029/5.049 secs] [Times: user=5.83 sys=0.31, real=5.05 secs] 
2018-07-29T18:53:00.355+0000: 73181.567: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 185778 K (1382400 K)]2018-07-29T18:53:00.355+0000: 73181.567: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0650261 secs]2018-07-29T18:53:00.420+0000: 73181.632: [weak refs processing, 0.0025795 secs]2018-07-29T18:53:00.423+0000: 73181.635: [class unloading, 0.0257172 secs]2018-07-29T18:53:00.448+0000: 73181.660: [scrub symbol table, 0.0026111 secs]2018-07-29T18:53:00.451+0000: 73181.663: [scrub string table, 0.9664343 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1414468K(1536000K)] 1600246K(2918400K), 1.0629217 secs] [Times: user=1.11 sys=0.00, real=1.06 secs] 
2018-07-29T18:53:01.418+0000: 73182.630: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.0657259 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002660 seconds

2018-07-30T12:30:12.498+0000: 136613.710: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-30T12:30:17.698+0000: 136618.910: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.185/5.200 secs] [Times: user=5.72 sys=0.20, real=5.20 secs] 
2018-07-30T12:30:17.701+0000: 136618.913: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 179068 K (1382400 K)]2018-07-30T12:30:17.701+0000: 136618.913: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0632593 secs]2018-07-30T12:30:17.764+0000: 136618.976: [weak refs processing, 0.0022151 secs]2018-07-30T12:30:17.767+0000: 136618.979: [class unloading, 0.1576453 secs]2018-07-30T12:30:17.924+0000: 136619.136: [scrub symbol table, 0.0043250 secs]2018-07-30T12:30:17.929+0000: 136619.141: [scrub string table, 1.0465825 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1414152K(1536000K)] 1593220K(2918400K), 1.2744338 secs] [Times: user=1.21 sys=0.00, real=1.28 secs] 
2018-07-30T12:30:18.976+0000: 136620.188: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.2772222 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001826 seconds

Comment: To start with I'd suggest removing all of the GC related options except the heap size (and selecting CMS) and rerunning the tests, or have you already tried that? A heap size of 300Mb is pretty small, can you make it any bigger? You've used a number of specific GC option choices and I'd like to know more about why. You're using incremental CMS, which is deprecated in JDK 8 and gone in JDK 9. This is typically used to alleviate the impact of GC on thruput and will make GC longer because you're sharing CPUs between GC and user work.

Comment: Also, why is MaxTenuringThreshold 1? This will force objects to be promoted into the old gen without making effective use of the survivor spaces. This, in turn, places greater load on the major GC. I would try reducing the InitiatingOccupancyFraction to say 50 and see if that improves things as it starts running the CMS earlier. I'll have a more detailed look at the GC log and see if I can see anything else.

Comment: My bad, I misread your args. I see now that you are setting the heap size to 3Gb, not 300Mb. As an Azul employee, I'm sure you could solve your problem by using the Zing JVM :-).

Comment: @Speakjava your advice to remove all these GC related options first, still is valid.

Comment: Fair enough, I have updated 2 of the vm's running atm, will see what the results look like on monday.